# Systemd tries to mount encfs at startup

Tags: systemd, encfs

I have a problem with systemd trying to mount my encfs drive `/dev/sdb1`.
Systemd asks for the password to encrypt the drive. This is only a problem when I'm updating Ubuntu, because the installation often halts while systemd is asking for the password. After aborting the password question, the installation continues but this is very annoying...

I don't want systemd to handle my encfs drive at all, I only mount it when I need it and this is done with the file manager, not through systemd. How can I tell systemd to disable automounting of this drive permanently?

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 22,4 GiB, 24015495168 bytes, 46905264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x020e1c69

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 46903295 46901248 22,4G 83 Linux
```

This is my `/etc/fstab`, there is no entry for `/dev/sdb1`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=de2463d2-cb58-4be5-b6aa-11c1b5b3241c /               ext4        errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add your encfs drive to `/etc/fstab` with the `noauto` option, this should tell to systemd unit not to mount the drive automatically. So you should add something similar:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/extdisk fuse noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```